# JDBC lock: how to tell an exception is caused by lock timeout?

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc, locking

JDBC lock:

```
select * from Foo for update
```

If lock fails, mysql will throw SQLTransactionRollbackException, and oracle will throw SQLException. How to tell if an exception is caused by lock (e.g. for update)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle, you will see ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object. The code can be checked by getting the err code from the SQLException.

```
       try {
          ...do work
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          int errCode = e.getErrorCode();

        }
```